# How to run Create Enterprise Geodatabase on PostgreSQL flexible server

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, azure

I am using:

- [Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-servers#managing-your-server) - version 13.10
- ArcGIS Pro (advanced license) - version 3.1.2

The ESRI documentation lists this version of PostgreSQL flexible server as [compatible](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/windows/databases-in-the-cloud.htm) with Pro 3.1. Further the [release notes](https://links.esri.com/arcgis-pro-issues-addressed-31x) for Pro 3.1.x state that it includes:

> ENH-000148704 Support the Microsoft Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server option

I am calling the [Create Enterprise Database](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/tool-reference/data-management/create-enterprise-geodatabase.htm) tool, passing it a new database name so it will create a new database and using the 'admin user' as the [superuser is not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-servers#managing-your-server) for this platform.

> User does not have required privileges to create database objects.
> [ERROR: User must be database SUPERUSER to create geodatabase.]

But if ArcGIS Pro is supports PostgreSQL flexible server then this tool must be able to run without superuser. Is there some part I am missing here?

Comment: I'm no expert here, but from this link: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/linux/databases-in-the-cloud.htm it states: If you do not use or cannot use the Esri cloud deployment tools to create the database, and you want to create a geodatabase in any of the supported database-as-a-service offerings listed above, you **must use the Enable Enterprise Geodatabase geoprocessing tool** to create a geodatabase. Do not use the **Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool.**

Comment: @KHibma Great! That's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using PostgreSQL flexible server, it is recommended to use the **Esri cloud deployment tools** for database creation. Using these tools allows you to use the **Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool**

Alternatively, you would use the **Enable Enterprise Geodatabase** tool if you deployed the database in another way.

[Reference documentation](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/linux/databases-in-the-cloud.htm)